# Why isn't the "if (member)" called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Currently creating a check to see if the id inputed were of a user, but it seems like "member" doesn't exist.
Code in question:

```
client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
    if (msg.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = msg.content
            .trim()
            .substring(PREFIX.length)
            .split(/\s+/);
        if (CMD_NAME == "kick") {
            if (args.length === 0) return msg.channel.send("Invalid user.");
            const member = msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
            if (member) {
                member
                    .kick()
                    .then((member) => msg.channel.send(`${member} was kicked.`))
                    .catch((err) => msg.channel.send(`I lack permissions to kick ${member.user}`));
            } else {
                msg.channel.send("User not found.");
            }
        }    
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds like `member` is falsey

Comment: Well, obviously `cache.get(args[0])` does not return what you expect it to. Check the content of `args[0]` and also the content of `member` at that location

Comment: Fetch the member. Do not rely on the cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would recommend to use fetch (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) instead of get, because the user maybe isn't cached. Also fetch needs a Snowflake(userid) to get the user, but you probably don't enter a userid, but rather a mention, which is in format '<@userid>' or '!@userid' so it needs to be parsed before you can call the function with the snowflake.

But in your case I would suggest to just use the built in features for mentions.

```
const member = msg.mentions.users.first();
```

Comment: Just want to comment on your first statement: First of all, `.get()` is documented under the Collection document: `https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get`. Second, fetching is not always the most reliable source, as in big guilds it may time out your bot, and could result in it crashing.

Comment: @Bqre How would fetching 1 user crash the bot? Yes it would crash if you fetch the whole guild...

Comment: @Logan Devine In fairly big guilds it is a possibility. It's not too common, but I did have it occur to me once or twice. Ever since then I'm not taking any more risks considering most discord users are already cached.

Comment: @Bqre With the latest API updates, very few members are cached.